# Javascript command for a text field that has entered text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

This might be a really stupid question but I cannot figure out the javascript command for the site to decide whether or not the text fields are filled based on whether or not the text fields are actually filled. My code is here.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Us</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<style type="text/css">
#main-container{
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
}
#left-bar{
text-align: right;
}
#left-bar, #right-bar{
border: 2px solid gray;
}
#top-nav-bar{
border-top: 1px solid gray;
border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
border-left: 2px solid gray;
border-right: 2px solid gray;
}
#navTextn{
float: right;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top:10px;
}
#navTextc{
float: right;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top:10px;
}
#navTexth{
float: right;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top:10px;
}
#Contus{
float:right;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top:10px;
}
#logo{
height: 20px;
width: 100px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding left: 10px;
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validator(){
        if(document.mUs.bfinderm.text)
            alert("Thank you for your submission");
        else
            alert("No text has been entered");
    }
</script>


<title>Tickit</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="topline">
</div>
<div id="top-nav-bar">
    <a href="Homework.html"><image id="Logo" src="Tickit.png"></a>
    <a id="Contus" href="ContactUs.html">Us</a>
    <a id="navTextn">News</a>
    <a id="navTextc" href="Calendar.html">Calendar</a>
    <a id="navTexth" href="Homework.html">Home</a>
</div>
<table id="main-container">

    <tr>
        <td id="left-bar" valign="top">
            <a id="plinks" >Profile</a><br>
            <a id="plinks" >Mail</a><br>
            <a id="plinks" href="Homework.html">Work Stream</a><br>
            <a id="plinks" href="calendar.html">Calendar</a><br>
            <a id="plinks" href="Events.html">Events</a><br>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td id="main" valign="top">
        If you find any bugs with the website, please leave a message to us in the box below <br> <br>
            <form name="mUs">
                Message Us:<br> <input type="text" name="bfinderm" />
                <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="validator()" />
            </form>
        </td>
        <td id="right-bar" valign="top">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Like in a check box, the validator() code would be the checked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validator(){
        if(document.stackflowrun.stflr.checked)
            alert("Yes it is checked!");
        else
            alert("Check that shit boul!");
    }
</script>
```

So what is the equivalent validator() command for the text field option?

```
function validator(){
        if(document.mUs.bfinderm.text)
            alert("Thank you for your submission");
        else
            alert("No text has been entered");
    }
</script>
```

(text is not it)

Comment: If you use just `val()` you can see what they input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `value` instead of `text`like this:

```
function validator(){
        if(document.mUs.bfinderm.value)
            alert("Thank you for your submission");
        else
            alert("No text has been entered");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

jquery: `$("#youridhere").val()` returns the input.
Add: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` to use jquery. Put that before your `<script>`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementById("bfindem").value.length > 0)
{
               alert("Thank you for your submission");
        else
}
            alert("No text has been entered");
}
```

In jQuery:

```
if ($("#bfindem").val().length > 0)
{
               alert("Thank you for your submission");
        else
}
            alert("No text has been entered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, modify your function as shown below

```
function validator(){
    if($('input[name="bfinderm"]').val().length !== 0)
        alert("Thank you for your submission");
    else
        alert("No text has been entered");
}
```

**[jQuery DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eqpnw/)**

Using straight Javascript, modify your function as shown here

```
function validator(){
    if($('input[name="bfinderm"]').val().length !== 0)
        alert("Thank you for your submission");
    else
        alert("No text has been entered");
}
```

**[Javascript DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kS4s7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try document.mUs.bfinderm.value - jquery not required